# Looking for a good source for learning ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been working with ASP.NET MVC for the last few weeks, learning as I go, from tutorials and mostly trial and error.

I'm sorta groping in the dark, since I have no other experience with MVC frameworks and I'm just moving ahead blindly trying to figure things out as I move along.

So, I'm looking for better, more organized source to learn the platform and its features, and in general, the MVC structure and how the framework implements it, but no books on the subject have been released yet, and are all due in a few months at best.

Does anyone know of any good, thorough resources from which I can expand my knowledge about the ASP.NET MVC framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rob Conery has his [ASP.NET MVC Storefront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/) series, which is what I used to get my feet wet.  It is around twenty-something parts long already.

He takes you threw the entire conceptual design and execution of an application, which is an incredible way to learn how something applies to the real world.

Answer (score 11):

I try to keep my articles simple and clear:

Concept / Getting Started:

- [ASP.NET MVC in the Real World](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/ASPNET_MVC_in_the_Real_World.aspx)
- [Building Custom ASP.NET MVC
  Controls](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Building_Custom_ASPNET_MVC_Controls.aspx)

Slightly more advanced / benefits of use:

- [AJAX Panels with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/AJAX_Panels_with_ASPNET_MVC.aspx)
- [MVC AJAX Sites That Gracefully Degrade](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/MVC_AJAX_Sites_That_Gracefully_Degrade.aspx)
- [Logging with ASP.NET MVC Action Filters](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Logging_with_ASPNET_MVC_Action_Filters.aspx)
- [Test Driven Development with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Test_Driven_Development_with_ASPNET_MVC.aspx)
- [Creating a Custom View Engine in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Creating_a_Custom_View_Engine_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx)

Each of those has a fully downloadable sample project. Most with screen shots.

EDIT: I should also add that [Jonathan Carter](http://www.lostintangent.com/) (a friend of mine who works for Microsoft up in Redmond) is someone that you should RSS. Here's one of his posts about MVC: [ASP.NET MVC - Action Filters](http://lostintangent.com/2008/07/08/aspnet-mvc-action-results/)

Answer (score 2):

Personally have found http://www.asp.net/mvc/ to be the best resource for me, the sample applications and other bits are very helpful

Answer (score 2):

As so often, codeproject has a very good tutorial on ASP.net MVC: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnet_mvc.aspx

Answer (score 2):

NerdDinner by Microsoft dev's - Phil Haack, Hanselman and ScottGu.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/03/10/chapter-one-pro-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I learned a lot from Scott Hanselman's [screencast on MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET35ExtensionsPlusMVCHowToScreencast.aspx). It's a little out of date as it was created last December, but it's a good into to the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Gunnerson's blog is a fantastic resource. [This post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/12/02/dec-2nd-links-asp-net-asp-net-dynamic-data-asp-net-ajax-asp-net-mvc-visual-studio-silverlight-wpf.aspx) will get you well on your way

Answer (score 1):

Get this book:

http://manning.com/palermo/

Also check out Ben Scheirman's blog:

http://flux88.com/

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you can't find any better book than "Pro ASP NET MVC Framework" by Steven Sanderson. I read many books but never read such good book.